# Get Sku, Name and Description Joined With 'Value' from `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`

Tags: database, product-images, sql, media

In order to migrate data between ERP systems, I need to rename images to conform to a specific format for the new system, coming from Magento. I'm going to write a script to automate this but need some data to start.

I'm able to pull sku, name and description using the query in this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23337745/how-to-pull-all-the-product-id-skus-product-names-description-in-magento-usin/23340108#23340108)

Currently all the paths for file images are in the 'value' column of the `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` table.

I'm wondering if there is a way to join the above query with the `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` table in order to retrieve the sku, name, description, and image file path.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT 
    `e`.`sku`, 
    IF(at_name.value_id > 0, at_name.value, at_name_default.value) AS `name`,
    IF(at_description.value_id > 0, at_description.value, at_description_default.value) AS `description`,
    at_path.value AS `path`

FROM 
   `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` 
    INNER JOIN 
         `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_name_default` 
               ON (`at_name_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND 
                  (`at_name_default`.`attribute_id` = (SELECT attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute` ea LEFT JOIN `eav_entity_type` et ON ea.entity_type_id = et.entity_type_id  WHERE `ea`.`attribute_code` = 'name' AND et.entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')) AND 
                  `at_name_default`.`store_id` = 0 
    LEFT JOIN 
          `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_name` 
               ON (`at_name`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND 
                  (`at_name`.`attribute_id` = (SELECT attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute` ea LEFT JOIN `eav_entity_type` et ON ea.entity_type_id = et.entity_type_id  WHERE `ea`.`attribute_code` = 'name' AND et.entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')) AND 
                  (`at_name`.`store_id` = 1) 
    INNER JOIN 
         `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `at_description_default` 
               ON (`at_description_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND 
                  (`at_description_default`.`attribute_id` = (SELECT attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute` ea LEFT JOIN `eav_entity_type` et ON ea.entity_type_id = et.entity_type_id  WHERE `ea`.`attribute_code` = 'description' AND et.entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')) AND 
                  `at_description_default`.`store_id` = 0 
    LEFT JOIN 
          `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `at_description` 
               ON (`at_description`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND 
                  (`at_description`.`attribute_id` = (SELECT attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute` ea LEFT JOIN `eav_entity_type` et ON ea.entity_type_id = et.entity_type_id  WHERE `ea`.`attribute_code` = 'description' AND et.entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')) AND 
                  (`at_description`.`store_id` = 1) 
    LEFT JOIN 
          `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` AS `at_path` 
               ON (`at_path`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`)
```